# rails 4 bootstrap group buttons with acts as taggable on edit, not pushed down

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using acts as taggable on gem and I'm trying to create a nice looking group button, but it doesn't stay marked if I'm editing the form. I know that the database did indeed save the value. I can even change the value and save when I edit, but when I go back to the edit button, it doesn't show which button got saved.

```
.btn-group{ data: { toggle: "buttons" } }
  - ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3"].each do |item|
    = f.label item, class: "btn btn-default" do
      = f.radio_button :tag_list, item
      = item
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Would like to have this on edit:

[image]

Am I missing a simple method that will show what the value is?

Answer (score 0):

Add `checked` attribute to your `radio_button`:

```
= f.radio_button :tag_list, item, checked: f.object.tag_list.include?(item)
```

Comment: are you referring to something like: `@mod = model.column` as the `saved_item` ? If so, didn't work. If in my controller `def edit @mod = Mod.find(params[:id]) end`

Comment: So, after selected, which value you saved to your db?

Comment: Oops, it should be `@mod = model.tag_list` Thats whats saved

Comment: @hellomello I see, I just updated the answer, check it out

Comment: Can you explain the `f.object`? This button is already going through `@mod = Model.find(params[:id])`, so the object supposed to be `models` (for this example)?. This button is under the `= simple_form_for @model do |f|`

Comment: 'f' is the form helper, f.object is your `@model`, you can use `@model` directly

Comment: Also, I looked at the inspect element, and would it be changing the label class to active instead? Because when I'm pressing down the button, the class adds an active.

Comment: yeah, it may be, let try

Comment: Is there a rails way to do so?

Comment: So just use `active` class for the current tag, right? No idea for a rails way, I just think we may define it view helper, but it is the same